# What is the return type of a list when there is more than one bean alias in the Hibernate query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

There is a Hibernate query :

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<> getClassificationOfPta() {

    String hql = "select p , c from Pta p join p.classePta c where c.niveau = 2 order by p.creation";

    Session sessionDynamic = Utils.createDynamicSession(env);

    Query query = sessionDynamic.createQuery(hql);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<> list = (List<>) query.list();

    sessionDynamic.close();

    return list;

}
```

So what is the thing to write inside the `<>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you leave the query as it is you will get a list of object arrays: `List<Object[]>`.

The zero index of the array will hold the Pta instance and the first index will hold the ClassPta instance.

You would have to unwrap that result set manually in that case.

There is a way to automate that process by the use of a Result Class:

```
package com.myapp;

public class Result{

     private Pta pta;
     private ClassPta classPta;

     public (Pta pta, ClassPta classPta){
          this.pta = pta;
          this.classPta = classPta;
    }

}
```

Then you would need to change the query and transactional method implementation as follows:

```
@Transactional
public List<Result> getClassificationOfPta() {

    String hql = "select new com.myapp.Result(p as pta, c as classPta) 
         from Pta p join p.classePta c where c.niveau = 2 order by p.creation";

    Session sessionDynamic = Utils.createDynamicSession(env);

    Query query = sessionDynamic.createQuery(hql);

    List<Result> list = (List<Result>) query.list();

    sessionDynamic.close();

    return list;

}
```

The second appraoch is more clean of course but the call is yours.